# Ionic 4 loading until images in page loaded

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62ild.png)I am using ionic 4 so i need to a loader untill the page loaded completely. Now i am using loadingController and dismiss it when api res, loading finished but images still loading. I want loading untill all loading finished.

Like ionic 3 ionViewDidLoad() works
Below is the Answer i found on Ionic Documentation an event called **ionImgWillLoad** but dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic 4 relies more on Angular lifecycle hooks and instead of ionViewDidLoad you should now use ngAfterViewInit hook.

View initialization means views’ layout and rendering of components has been finished, but images async loading can still be ongoing.

ionViewDidLoad in Ionic 3 was also not awaiting for images to load. To have such a "hook" one needs to to custom implementation.

In typescript something like the below would do the trick:

```
counter: number;
maxImagesCount: number = document.images.length;

updateCounter() {
    this.counter++;
    if ( this.counter === this.maxImagesCount ) {
        console.log( 'All images loaded!' );
    }
}
```

In the template you could attach load event listener to images templates:

```
<img src="url" (load)="updateCounter()">
```

Comment: But My question is to load until images are loaded... i have tried ngAfterViewInit hook. its not work like that.. it load to early

Comment: So there is no out of box API or a hook that would give you that (ability to say when images are loaded on the page fully). You have to implement your own custom logic and tie it to img element's "load" event.

Comment: your custom function does make sense but it is not working document.images.forEach( (image) => {
    image.addEventListener( 'load', updateCounter);
} );  angular doesn't have onload event? or anything similar to that?

Comment: please check I updated the approach that should work in Angular

Answer (score 1):

The closest to ionViewDidLoad is probably ionViewDidEnter. See the life cycle events below:
[image]